# How to prove whether or not $g : ( \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^2, g(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,xy)$ is one to one.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-explanation

For reference, I am in Introduction to Abstract Math, and I have taken Calculus 1, Discrete Math, and Introduction to Linear Algebra.

I am trying to prove or disprove that $g : ( \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^2, \:\:g(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,xy)$ is one to one.

I know the definition of a one-to-one function is that a function $f : A \to B$ is one-to-one if for all $a_1, a_2 \in A$, whenever $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$, then $a_1=a_2$.

Due to the domain of $g$, I know that $x>0$, and I also have proven that $g$ is not onto with the counterexample of there being no $g(x,y)$ such that $g(x,y)=(0,0)$. I also have values for $x^2$ and $-y^2$, which are $x^2=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}}{2}$ and $-y^2=\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}}{2}$. However, I am unsure of where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x$ is positive you get a  unique value for $x$ from what you have already done. There are two possibilities for $y$ but $xy=b$ shows that there is only one value for $y$ also. So $g$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Since Kavi Rama Murthy's answer addresses the OP's question, it's open season.

alternative approach

Assume $x^2 - y^2 = r^2 - s^2$ and $xy = rs = t \neq 0.$

Then $y = (x/t)$ and $s = (r/t)$ implies

$[E_1]: x^2 (1 - [1/t]) = r^2 (1  - [1/t]).$

If $t = 1$, then $y = x$ and $r = s$ implies

$x^2 = r^2$ implies $x = r$.

WLOG, $t \neq 1.$

Then, by $[E_1]$ (again) $x^2 = r^2$ implies $x = r$.

Thus, $y = (x/t) = (r/t) = s.$

Comment: What is $[E_1]$?

Comment: see 5th line in my answer